# Получение|отправка геолокации пользователя посредством aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram, геолокация

Пытаюсь реализовать такую вещь: пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Share location", бот обрабатывает эту информацию, сохраняя широту и долготу в отдельные переменные, затем отправляет это дело в виде геопозиции и уточняет, верный ли это адрес.
Пытался сделать все посредством фильтров, присутствующих в aiogram, однако третья версия не позволяет подобного, либо об этом просто нигде не сказано.
Решения я находил, однако все они были для aiogram 2.
Так вот, основная суть вопроса - каким образом поймать событие отправки локации пользователем и следственно занести широту и долготу в переменные?

Answer (score 0):

```
locations = {}

@dp.message(F.location)
async def location_handler(message: types.Message):
    latitude = message.location.latitude
    longitude = message.location.longitude
    locations['latitude'] = latitude
    locations['longitude'] = longitude
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]